# C# MSSQL base64 insert and select. Data differs

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf, utf-8, base64

Im having a bit of a challenge here, I hope that some of you clever guys out there can guide/show me to a solution.
The code has been condensated/cut down a bit to ease you. Hense if a program error occurs, it is due to that.

The task of the program is to download a pdf from a URL, and save the PDF on a MS SQL server.

I can save it but it seems the data changes. E.g. The first byte from the downloaded PDF is 25h (correct) and when I save it in the database it changes to 1Fh (wrong).

I realise it must be the conversion between the download and saving, but unfortunately I cant make it work.

```
// This is where I suspect that my problem occurs.
byte[] myDataBuffer = client.DownloadData((new Uri(strFileUrlToDownload)));
```

Please excuse me if Im not clear in my writing. English isn't my first language.

Thanks in advance.

Script for create table and C# code below.

Script for creating the table on MS SQL server:

```
SET [ThePartikularDatabase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PDFTable](
[DokumentAID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ident] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[AB] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[BI] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[dokumentType] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[base64] [varbinary](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Here comes the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO; 
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace test
{

class program
{



    public static void DownloadData(string strFileUrlToDownload, WebClient client, string IV_ident, string IV_AB, string IV_BI, string IV_dokumentType)
    {
        // This function is made with inspiration from: 
    // http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/013102/save-and-read-pdf-file-using-sql-server-and-C-Sharp/

        byte[] myDataBuffer = client.DownloadData((new Uri(strFileUrlToDownload)));

        //string encodedText = Convert.ToBase64String(myDataBuffer);
        //string decodedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myDataBuffer);

        //  byte[] lars = Convert.ToByte(encodedText);


        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GlobalVar.ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Database].[dbo].[PDFTable] " + "(Ident, AB, BI, dokumentType, base64) values (@ident, @AB, @BI, @dokumentType, @data);", cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", myDataBuffer);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ident", ident);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@AB", IV_AB);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@BI", IV_BI);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@dokumentType", IV_dokumentType);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }



        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GlobalVar.ConnectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [base64] FROM [Database].[dbo].[PDFTable] WHERE ident = " + IV_ident + " ;", cn))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default))
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        byte[] fileData = (byte[])dr.GetValue(0);
                        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("c:\\" + IV_ident + ".pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            using (System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs))
                            {
                                bw.Write(fileData);
                                bw.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    dr.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }



    public static void SaveMemoryStream(MemoryStream ms, string FileName)
    {
        FileStream outStream = File.OpenWrite(FileName);
        ms.WriteTo(outStream);
        outStream.Flush();
        outStream.Close();
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int LI_start = 0;
        int LI_slut = 0;
        int LI_documentURL = 0;

        string LS_ident = "";
        string credentials = "Username:Password";
        string url = "http://pdfurl.com/find;


        CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
        Regex regex = new Regex("");



        try
        {  
            /*

        ident is fetched from our database. Code removed for simplicity..
        */
                LS_ident = Convert.ToString(theRow["ident"]);
                string LS_json = "{\"from\":0,\"size\":1,\"query\":{\"term\":{\"ident\":" + LS_ident + "}}}";
                string LS_pdfURL = "";



                string reply = client.UploadString(url, "POST", LS_json);


                /********************************************************/
                /* Regex ************************************************/
                /*
        URL for the pdf is taken from the reply with Regular expression.
                */
        /* Regex ************************************************/
                /********************************************************/




                LS_pdfURL = "" + dokURL[i].Substring(LI_start, (LI_slut + 1 - LI_start)) + "pdf";
        /*
        LS_pdfURL now contains the correct path for the pdf.
        I can manually download the pdf with the url. It works.
        So far, so good.
        */  
                DownloadData(LS_pdfURL, client, LS_ident, "StartDato", "SlutDato", "Doktype");




                /**/
                //break;
            }
            thisConnection.Close();

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Der skete en fejl: (get) {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        /**/

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is the base64 column image or text/ntext?  If the later I would have expected you to have to convert the byte[] yourself using System.Convert.ToBase64String(myDataBuffer).

Comment: @BenJackson The datatypes `IMAGE`, `TEXT` and `NTEXT` are depricated... I'd assume the Base64 column to be of type `VARCHAR(MAX)` or maybe `VARBINARY` ...

Comment: I've just added the create table script.

Comment: Please try to find out where the problem occurs: There are tons of online converters to find. put a small PDF in your column, retrieve the value via SSMS and try a de-coding. You've to find out if the error happens on writing or reading. And please give further details, especially about the data type you are writing into...

Comment: Thx for the table's structure... `SELECT SomeVarbinary FROM SomeWhere` will show up as HEX string...

Comment: One question: Why are you converting to Base64 at all? This is meant to store binary data in text containers (such as XML or HTML). It was better to fill your `byte[]` into `VARBINARY` *as is* ...

Comment: @Shnugo: 1.
Select SomeVarbinary from somewhere. Will show up as HEX string. isn't that the same as base64?
2.It's because we need this partikular format afterwards, to solve another problem.

Comment: No, google for "hex vs base64 encoding" ...

Comment: Still I would suggest to store the PDF *as is* and to conversion in the appropriate place. You would not keep your money in a foreign currency only because you want to travel there later :-)

Comment: @Shnugo: Thanks very much. Is there any way I can give you points for guiding me to a solution. By the way I changed to varchar(max). Again thanks.

Comment: @LarsHansen I just placed an answer with a summary of this and would be happy if you vote it up and accept it, thx! Glad that you could solve this!

Comment: @Shnugo: Request for more information.
Can you give me a last hint?
When I try to save the downloaded file it changes content???

using (WebClient clientx = new WebClient())
                            {
                                clientx.DownloadFile(LS_pdfURL, @"C:\trash\Temp.pdf");
                            }
When I download it manually (copy the url and insert in browser) then it works and the content is correct. When C# does it, the pdf is corrupted.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know what you load and how you save... If you load a byte-stream and you try to save this in `VARCHAR()` it will save something, but for sure not what you expect... If you convert this to base64 and save this to `VARCHAR()` it will be saved properly but you cannot open it as PDF anymore. If you want the byte-stream back (which is the PDF) you mus decode it back. Try with online tools to find out, what you've got actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has it's reason with the different encodings.

Base64 is meant to store binary data *within* string based containers such as XML or HTML by using a reduced set of characters. The encoded content **is a string** consisting of "secure characters" only and can be handled as any other string.

A Hex-String is a chain of bits. They are packed in groups of 4 and displayed with characters from 0 to 9 and A to F... Behind the scenes this is just a chain of bits, packed in groups and *displayed* as string of 16 characters. This needs - **but only in characters!** - more space than base64... as a bit-chain it needs less...

It is always necessary to think about: What type has my data and which is the appropriate type to store this?

You decided to place your base64 within a column of type `VARCHAR(MAX)`. Seems to be a good choice. But I'd still prefer the `VARBINARY(MAX)` and do the base64 encoding when I need it.

Comment: May I know what is "secure characters" meant? Can give some examples of "insecure character"?

Comment: @YisiTan, Base64 ist nothing else than a hack to *embed* binaries into text-based containers. Within XML you do not want to find `<` or `&`, in JSON som `[`, `{` or `"` might disturb. What is *not secure* acutally depends on the given container. Base64 will use `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `+` or `/`. The `=` is used as "filler" at the end. But always keep in mind, that the real *value* is a binary.